# Perl execution from command line question

Tags: perl, command-line, strawberry-perl

I replaced ActivePerl with Strawberry Perl on my WinXP last week.

I found I must run my Perl script with the command of `perl myperl.pl`; otherwise I only need run `myperl.pl` before install Strawberry. How can I only run `myperl.pl` as before?

I checked my environment configuration as below.

> ```
> C:\> Path
>
> C:\Program Files\ActiveState Komodo Edit
> 5\;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Perl\bin\;C:\Program Files\CodeSynthesis
> XSD 3.2\bin\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
> C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI Control Panel;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
> SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Thunder Network\KanKan
> \Codecs;C:\strawberry\c\bin;C:\strawberry\perl\bin`
> ```

Strawberry Perl path already listed in the Path value after install successfully.

Anything I missed? Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try from command prompt:

```
assoc .pl=PerlScript
ftype PerlScript=c:\strawberry\bin\perl.exe %1 %*
```

--
kmx

Comment: It doesn't work on my side. I ran the two lines from windows command window successfully.  But I tried to run my Perl script, It still failed. I don't know why?

Comment: It works. I realized that my computer Perl Script Path should be `c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe` in the command.
http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ftype.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 8):

You need to associate `.pl` file extension with Strawberry Perl's executable (it's a Windows thing, not a Perl thing).

To do so, there are a couple of ways (you can google or ask on ServerFault for the best one or full list), but the one I usually use on XP is:

- Open any folder Windows Explorer
- Go into "Tools" menu, and click on "File Types" tab in the resulting dialog
- Find "PL" extension in the list
- If it's there, correct the associated executable to be Strawberry Perl's .exe by clicking on "PL" line and clicking "Change" button
- If it's not in the list, click "New" button, type in PL extension in the form and click "OK". Then close the whole dialog, and re-open it again. The "PL" extension will now be in the list, so click on it and click "Change" button

In case I messed up, here's the official instructions from Microsoft:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859

**UPDATE**
Please see kmx's answer - his method is all-command-line and as such seems much more preferable to me that GUI blundering... I confirmed that it works too (without parameters, at least)

Comment: @Nano - please see kmx's answer - his method is all-command-line and as such seems much more preferable to me... I confirmed that it works too!

Comment: Use the proper technique: See kmx's amswer

Answer (score 3):

You might need to put the `.PL` extension into the `PATHEXT` environment variable. This will make `.pl` files work with the `PATH` variable.

Type

```
set PATHEXT
```

to see if you're set up. If you're not, then go to My Computer->properties->Advanced and press the "Environment Variables" button on the bottom of the tab. There you can add `.PL` to the `PATHEXT` variable.

OR you could just set it in some batch file that you run to initiate cmd:

```
set PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.PL
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question, but it is noneless an other useful tip that will help the poster.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here's 2 other methods that don't make a .pl script executable, but you could use them to make your perl script into an executable.

- [pl2bat](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?pl2bat) which is suppose to create a wrapped version of your .pl into a .bat file which would be executable on a windows system. I haven't tried this so YMMV.
- [pp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PAR%3a%3aPacker), part of the [PAR::Packer](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR-Packer/) module which I have used before works pretty well at rolling your perl scripts into executables.