# Associating .pl files with Perl on Windows 10

Tags: perl, cmd, admin

Everytime when I work with Perl (only through cmd) I put in `C:\Perl520\Perl64\bin\perl.exe` before my script `Test.pl`.
Now I want to run my script by only typing `Test.pl`. I have already looked through similiar questions like:

https://docs.sdl.com/791187/706364/sdl-contenta-5-7/associating--pl-files-with-strawberry-perl--windows-only-

[How Do I Run a Perl Script from Cmd without typing "perl" in front of the script path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110797/how-do-i-run-a-perl-script-from-cmd-without-typing-perl-in-front-of-the-script)

I want to change this WITHOUT needing Admin Rights, as these are restricted on my computer.

I have even tried writing this in cmd:

```
assoc .pl=PerlScript
ftype PerlScript=C:\Perl520\Perl64\bin\perl.exe "%1" %*
```

Also here I keep getting the error message "Access is denied".

Is it possible to change the settings in another way?

EDIT: I managed to make it work through the first link. Yet I couldn't make it further after step 6 as once again I would need admin rights.
At least I am now able to run a script by just typing `Test.pl`.

But when using an input file :`Test.pl C:\input.txt`
I once again get an error message "Could not locate file!"
When writing it like this, it works as usual:

`C:\Perl520\Perl64\bin\perl.exe Test.pl C:\input.txt`

Comment: Are you comfortable with the Windows Registry?  If so, have a look inside the Registry for the change you made for "Open With".  I think it's in a non-admin section of the Registry, probably HKCU.  Then, see if you can modify those settings to do something like in my answer linked below.  If you can mod your registry entry to do this, then you can export that registry key to a .REG script that others can use too, in case you need this for co-workers.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705851/how-do-i-create-drag-and-drop-strawberry-perl-programs/706389#706389

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the file type association mechanism does require local admin rights. You *can* right-click on the script file and then pick `perl.exe` from the "Open With" menu, but that won't let you pass command line arguments to the string.

You might just want to run `pl2bat` on scripts you use often.