# How can I make a Perl script executable in Windows 64bit?

Tags: windows, perl

I am trying to run the perl script through command line but it is not reorganizing the script file ie.

myscript.pl... is not working
but perl myscript.pl is working fine

I have tried the following suggestions but they didn't work either

[How do I make my Perl scripts act like normal programs on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727480/how-do-i-make-my-perl-scripts-act-like-normal-programs-on-windows)

[Perl execution from command line question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013341/perl-execution-from-command-line-question)

I am using Active Perl:- Perl 5 , Version 18.

It gives following warnings in both cases.
Using a hash as a reference is deprecated

earlier I installed strawberry perl before installing active perl, is that causing some problem.

Comment: I just realized that the existing answers are very comprehensive. If those didn't work, this seems a tricky problem on your specific setup. Can you post more information about the error you get when you try to launch the script?

Comment: It doesn't give any errors, it just give few warnings which it gives while running it with perl keyword also.

Comment: Can you copy here those warnings?

Comment: included in question only @Lorenzo

Comment: Just a suggestion but how about running `pl2bat myscript.pl` and then double clicking `myscript.bat`

Comment: That to is not working

Comment: OK... so what's the exact different behavior of the two cases?

Comment: @Lorenzo In the first case it just gives the warning but the script is not executed but in the second case it is executing the script fine.

Answer (score 1):

The error message

```
Using a hash as a reference is deprecated
```

is a Perl message. Your script is being run just fine, but contains an error.

(It is remotely possible that you have two Perl versions installed, and that you configured Windows to use the wrong one. Reconfigure it to use the correct on then, using the guides you already found.)

Comment: I uninstalled the strawberry one then I installed the Active perl, is it still possible that the strawberry perl Is still installed. assoc .pl=PerlScript
ftype PerlScript=C:\perl\bin\perl.exe "%1" %*, through this command I m pointing to my Active Perl directory. C:\Perl\bin this is the path to perl.exe

Comment: Without proper technical diagnostics, anything is "possible". You should update the question to describe **exactly** what you did and **exactly** what the problem is.